# How do I append a lambda to a list in python?

Tags: python, lambda, append

I am trying to make a program that creates a list of lambda functions of the format `y=mx+b`, where 'm' and 'b' are predetermined values

**My overall goal is to implement a function** that

- Takes a picture
- Finds the lines on it
- Extends them across the whole picture in a solid colour

Basically, something like a **Hough transforms** if you know what that is.

Once I have the lines for a specific image, I can create a lambda function to represent the slope of the line and where it begins. I'm having an issue not being able to append a lambda function to the list.

I have tried this :

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  nums = []
  for i in range(10):
    j = lambda x: x + i
    nums.append(j)
  for i in nums:
    print(i(1))
```

Here is the error I'm getting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/me/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(i(1))
  File "C:/Users/me/.PyCharmCE2018.3/config/scratches/scratch_3.py", line 4, in <lambda>
    j = (lambda x: x + i)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'function'
```

Comment: Look here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/lambdas.html

Comment: so i looked at that site and basically i tried changing the "i" to a "1" and that worked fine. why can'y i use "i" instead? for my real project i kind of need to have a changeable variable in there.

Comment: See https://sopython.com/canon/30/why-do-my-lambda-functions-or-nested-functions-created-in-a-loop-all-use-the-las/

Comment: The specific error occurs because the name `i` used to iterate over the functions, is what will be looked up in the lambda.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the lambdas you create are referring to the current value of `i` in the active stack frame.  When you later reuse `i` for the second `for` loop, it is bound to the lambdas in your list.  When invoked as `i(1)`, the lambdas are trying to evaluate `1 + i` where `i` is the lambda, so of course you get an error.

Probably what you want is to freeze the value of `i` at the point at which the lambda is created.  You can do this by replacing:

```
j = lambda x: x + i
```

with:

```
j = (lambda y: lambda x: x + y)(i)
```

This effectively captures the current value of `i` by binding it to a lambda variable, then immediately applying that lambda, after which the binding remains fixed.

Comment: Or `lambda x, i=i: x + i`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I think that would work as well, although it would allow for a second argument to be passed that overrides that captured value of `i`.

Comment: ok i dont mean to sound stupid but how could i apply that to a lambda that needs 2 variables? like my mx+b function, where x is the thing that changes, and b and m are already declared but will change with every iteration in the for loop?

Comment: As an example, if you want to capture 3 values, say `i1`, `i2`, and `i3`, then you could do:  `j = (lambda y1, y2, y3: lambda x: x + y1 + y2 + y3)(i1, i2, i3)`.  Of course, you could do whatever you want with them in the inner lambda, but you get the idea.

Comment: ```if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(10):
        j += 1
        H = (lambda y: lambda x: y)(j)
        L = (lambda y: lambda x: H(x) + y)(i)
        nums.append(L)
    for i in nums:
        print(i(1))

Answer (score 5):

This will give you a clue:

```
>>> i=1
>>> a=lambda x:x+i
>>> a(5)
6
>>> i=2
>>> a(5)
7
```

`lambda` uses i in the outer scope.  In the OP case, all the functions are the same.  Using `i` in the final loop makes `i` a function, not an integer.  Change it to something else, and you'll find the functions are all the same, using the last value of `i`:

```
nums = []
for i in range(10):
    j = lambda x: x + i
    nums.append(j)
for f in nums:
    print(f(1))
```

> ```
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> 10
> ```

The fix is, make `i` a parameter to the function, to capture the value as a local variable:

```
nums = []
for i in range(10):
    j = lambda x,i=i: x + i
    nums.append(j)
for f in nums:
    print(f(1))
```

> ```
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
> ```

Comment: is that default parameter? clever way : )

Comment: Wow that is pretty sneaky. I like it. thanks a ton for the answer by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Your value of *i* has changed and it's not what you think.

First you create lambda:

```
j = lambda x: x + i
```

in hope, that i will remain as CURRENT value (so 0, 1, 2 and so on).

Then you execute it:

```
print(i(1))
```

Do you see, how you named your second iterator variable *i*? Change it to *j* and your example will work. Why? Because python resolves value of *i* in your lambda, when you execute it, not when you define it. So when you execute your lambda (*i(1)*) it will go to your lambda body and try *x + i*. Then it will lookup *i*, which now contains your lambda (not the INTEGER!). Hence your problem.

You need to do double function to make it work properly. Try this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  nums = []
  for i in range(10):
    def generate_lambda(i):
      return lambda x: x + i
    j = generate_lambda(i)
    nums.append(j)
  for i in nums:
    print(i(1))
```

Why does this work? When you call *generate_lambda*, there will be *i* variable with your INTEGER value. It will shadow variable *i* used later on to iterate over lambdas. And since you never modify *i* variable inside *generate_lambda* function, it will stay like this forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to learn something more about lambda functions...
Actually, it's syntax is like : [*lambda arguments: expression*]
So, the issue is you have two variables in the expression, so you need to pass two arguments.
I don't really get what you want to achieve by this function, but I guess you need to have two arguments for m and b.

In your code, you need to initialize x and pass it as an argument to lambda.

```
            nums = []
            x=0
            for i in range(10):
                j = lambda x,i : x + i
                nums.append(j)
            for i in nums:
                print(i(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use operator.add and functools.partial and do not lambda at all:

```
import operator
import functools


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = []

    for i in range(10):
        nums.append(functools.partial(operator.add, i))
    for i in nums:
        print(i(1))
```